# How do I input HTML into the help text of a Django form field?

Tags: django, django-forms

I tried to generate help text for a Choice Field in my Django form with

```
i_agree = forms.CharField(label="", help_text="Initial to affirm that you agree to the <a href='/contract.pdf'>contract</a>.", required=True, max_length="4")
```

However, the raw HTML is rendered as output in the help text. How do I input HTML into the help text of a Django form field?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) in the model to indicate the html is safe and it should be interpreted as such:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

i_agree = forms.CharField(label="", help_text=mark_safe("Initial to affirm that you agree to the <a href='/contract.pdf'>contract</a>."), required=True, max_length="4")
```

Comment: You can also apply this directly to the `help_text` for that field: `self.fields['i_agree'].help_text = mark_safe("Initial to affirm that you agree to the <a href='/contract.pdf'>contract</a>.")`

Answer (score 13):

You can alternatively mark it as safe in the template if you loop through the form yourself:

```
{% for f in form %}
    {{f.label}}{{f}}{{f.help_text|safe}}    
{%endfor%}
```

That's a very simple example of doing so in the template.  You would need to do more than that to make it look nice.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it wouldn't work with the automated output of `form.as_[p,ul,table]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an external file to increase maintainability and separation of concern:

1. modify yourform's `__init__()` method ;
2. after the `super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` ;
3. assign the result of `render_to_string()` to `self.fields['my_field'].help_text`.

### *forms.py*

from django.template.loader import render_to_string

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Only in case we build the form from an instance,
        if 'instance' in kwargs and kwargs['instance'].nature == consts.RiskNature.RPS:
            self.fields['my_field'].help_text = render_to_string('components/my-template.html')
            #                      ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

### *my-template.html*

```
{% load i18n %}
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>{% trans 'Externe' %}</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody class="text-muted">
        <tr>
              <td>{% trans "En lien avec les relations de travail" %}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>{% trans "-" %}</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Swings and roundabouts - yes it's nice to have the HTML in an external file but overridden save methods can end up full of unrelated functionality - and you've got help_text being set somewhere you wouldn't expect to look. Could you put the render_to_string directly onto the field definition itself?

Answer (score -6):

Use a textarea tag with readonly

```
<textarea readonly> <p>stuff</p> </textarea>
```